# How to map an array from response API to select element in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, select, axios, map-function

I am trying to get put the data from an array to  in react. I first retrieve the array from api response and store in `state`.  Below is my code which fail to get the value but key to `<select>`?

```
temp_list = [
            0:{fruit:"apple"},
            1:{fruit:"orange"}]

const f_list = this.state.fruit
const tmp_list = Object.keys(f_list).map((item, index) => <option value={item.fruit} >{item.fruit}</option>);
```

The result of `<select> option` will b:

```
0
1
```

Expected:

```
apple
orange
```

How can I achieve what I want? Thanks

Comment: You put `react-select` in the title. Can I assume that you are referring to a `select` element in a react environment, as opposed to the [`react-select` library](https://react-select.com/home)?

Comment: well your data structure is not correct `temp_list ` it may be like `[
            {fruit:"apple"},
            {fruit:"orange"}]`

Comment: @George yes, i'm referring to select element. Already amended the title. Thanks for your remind

Comment: @ManjeetThakur the data I printed in console is as same as above. If the array is like yours, how to change my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `f_list` is an `object`. Then you should try this,

```
const tmp_list = Object.keys(f_list).map((item, index) => <option value={f_list[item].fruit} >{f_list[item].fruit}</option>);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-btn8xs)